# Detect if keyboard is shown in android with navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-softkeyboard

I've already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android) but `onGlobalLayout()` never gets called.
Yes, I've already set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest.

Maybe it is because I'm using a `DrawerLayout` as my activity root layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/activity_drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" />

<!-- The navigation drawer -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/user_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I've tested `activity_drawer_layout` and `main_fragment_layout` in `findViewById()` but unsuccessfully; `onGlobalLayout()` never gets called. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure as to what are you trying to achieve by identifying whether your keyboard is visible or not, but if you only want to hide the keyboard when the navigation drawer is opened, I suggest you use the following code

```
private void hideKeyboard() {   
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

Also did you take a look at [How to check visibility of software keyboard in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android)

Comment: I just wanna know if keyboard is hidden or shown. And onGlobalLayout() method never gets called.